# Django is_authenticated always return False

Tags: django, cpanel, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth and cpanel to develop a website. Everything works fine, but there is one problem. I always get false in this statement:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
```

The strangest thing is that everything works fine on local. But, it always returns false on the real site (using cpanel) even though I'm already logged in. One more weird thing I found (which might be a clue) is I can log in with different accounts at different tabs.

I don't know what is the problem. I don't even know where to check the problem. Is the problem in django-allauth? cpanel? session? Where should I check?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I'm using `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` on the template and it works fine. Also when I tried to type the URL manually, it works fine. The problem is only when I click the URL from the footer link.

Here is my views.py

```
elif slug == "submit-a-vineyard":
    vineyard_form = VineyardForm()
    vineyard_user_form = VineyardUserForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            vineyard_form = VineyardForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            vineyard_user_form = VineyardUserForm(request.POST)
            if vineyard_form.is_valid() and vineyard_user_form.is_valid():
                instance1 = vineyard_form.save(commit=False)
                instance1.save()
                vineyard_form.save_m2m()
                instance2 = vineyard_user_form.save(commit=False)
                instance2.vineyard = instance1
                instance2.name = request.user.username
                instance2.email1 = request.user.email
                instance2.save()
                request.session["vineyard_form_msg"] = "Your vineyard has been successfully submitted!"
                return redirect("pages_app:mainpage")
    else:
        request.session["submit_vineyard"] = True
        return redirect("account_login")
```

Here is my templates:

```
          <li>
            <a
              href="{{ footer.link }}"
              {% if footer.new_window %} target="_blank" {% endif %}
              class="text-white-50"
              style="text-decoration: none"
              >{{ footer.title }}</a
            ><br />
          </li>
```

When I inspect an element, the URL that I type is same as the footer link. But when I click the footer link, it always redirects me to the login page even when I'm logged in.

Comment: While login with different accounts, you won't get the message of `bad request` from django?

Comment: No, I don't get any bad requests from django @SunderamDubey